streamlit st.text_input: value not updating as expected
New to streamlit, this is my issue: I’m trying to provide the user with an interface to annotate some data. For each item the user should give a label and may optionally leave a comment, and they can navigate across the different items with ‘prev’ and ‘next’ buttons. A basic version of the code is here:
import streamlit as st

N=10

choices_values = ['No label', 'YES','NO', 'NA/unclear']
choices_position = { choice:i for i,choice in enumerate(choices_values) }
map_choice_to_value = { 'No label': None, 'YES': 1, 'NO': 0, 'NA/unclear': -1}
map_value_to_choice = { value:key for key, value in map_choice_to_value.items() }

# go to next pair
def next_pair():
    st.session_state.current_index += 1

# go to previous pair
def prev_pair():
    st.session_state.current_index -= 1

# save 
def change_label():
    choice = st.session_state.select_label
    st.session_state.labels[st.session_state.current_index] = map_choice_to_value[choice]

def edit_comment_area():
    st.session_state.comments[st.session_state.current_index] = st.session_state.comment_area



top_text = st.markdown('**Loading data...**')
# initialize state variables
if 'labels' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.labels = [None] * N
if 'comments' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.comments = [None] * N
if 'current_index' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.current_index = 0
n_labels = sum(x is not None for x in st.session_state.labels)
top_text.markdown(f"**Item {st.session_state.current_index+1}/{N}** ({n_labels}/{N} annotated)")


# User input: label choice
current_label = st.session_state.labels[st.session_state.current_index]
st.radio('Are these two reports similar?', 
                    options= choices_values,
                    index = choices_position[map_value_to_choice[current_label]],
                    key = 'select_label',
                    on_change=change_label)

# User input: optional comments
st.text(st.session_state.comments[st.session_state.current_index])
st.text_area('Comment (optional)', 
                key='comment_area',
                value = st.session_state.comments[st.session_state.current_index],
                on_change=edit_comment_area)

# UI: Previous and next buttons to navigate across the pairs
#
prev_button = st.button('Previous', 
                        on_click=prev_pair, 
                        disabled=st.session_state.current_index == 0)
next_button = st.button('Next', 
                        on_click=next_pair,
                        disabled=st.session_state.current_index == N-1)

The labels part work well: when the user changes a label for item X, navigates to other items, then comes back to item X, they will find the last label they selected for X.
However the comments don’t work: when the user enters a comment it is correctly stored in st.session_state.comments and it can be printed by st.write, but even though the value arg in st.text_area is set to the right text, it does not show up in the text area as expected.
I noticed a few things: entering a comment for item X then another comment for the previous or next item and immediately going back makes the comment appear in the text_area for X. However navigating again in other comments makes both disappear, even though st.session_state.comments contains the correct value.
Am I missing something? How do I obtain the expected behaviour?

I didn't run it but if it would be different GUI then in prev_pair() I would add code which replace text in label and text_area - I wouldn't expect that GUI will replace it automatically

I run your code and it works correctly for me. I can't reproduce this problem.  Tested on Streamlit 1.27.2, Python 3.10, Linux Mint, Firefox 126. Maybe problem makes browser - maybe it can't run fast enough to replace it.

I can see problem only if I very fast put comment and very fast press button - but it is very hard to do it fast enough. It keep comment in text area in next questions but it doesn't save it in state. If I move back to question which has correctly added comment then it start displaying correct comments.

probably in has problem to clear area because it runs too fast. Maybe it shows some error in JavaScript console in DevTools. But I think author didn't expect that someone will switch it so fast and code update content in browser too slow.

@furas thank you for your comments, I didn't realize this issue could depend on hardware/browser, so will try with different browsers. But I don't fully understand how speed would cause my issue: I know that the comment is correctly stored in list st.session_state.comments because the st.text just before st.text_area correctly shows the right text. So to me it looks as if the st.text_area line is not executed whereas the st.text is.

About your first point, I'm also interested to try but I don't know how I can modify the value of a widget argument from its key. Can I just do something like st.session_state.comment_area.value=my_new_value ?
